# Длинное или краткое слово - что раньше?

Tags: словообразование

Учитывая приведенные нами русско-санскритские пары (Исследование - "Кому понадобилась русская ИЗБА ?") возник вопрос:
При заимствованиях из далеких языков могут ли новые слова из коротких становиться длинными?

Вот примеры рус.-санскр. пар:
Дать — да; Дровяной, деревянный — Дравья; Дурной, плохой — Дур; Изба — Зба; Кашлять — Кас, Каш; Ласкать, обнимать — Лас; Лизать — Лих, Лиз; Любить — Лубх; Меркнуть, мрачнеть— Мрчь; Мокнуть — Мок и многие-многие другие.

Скажем, если наши предки взяли у индусов слово ЛУБХ или МОК, какие законы языка могли из них сделать русск. ЛЮБИТЬ и МОКНУТЬ?

Answer (score 1):

"Законы" очевидны. "Краткое слово" тут – это корень, а "длинное" – корень, увешанный русскими морфами: "ть" – суффикс инфинитива, "ян/янн" — суффикс прилагательного и так далее.

Сравните "короткое слово" вязь и "длинные слова" вязать, связывать, связующий и многие другие. Ситуация почти та же самая.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я подготовлю для Вас и позже допишу здесь новый аргумент, где покажу русско-санскритскую пару, в которой русское будет КОРОТКИМ,  а санскритское, напротив, ДЛИННЫМ словом, т.е. обвешанным морфами.

Основной вопро состанется тем же.
С уважением, Федор.

Comment: Пересвет, слов таких оказалось много. Привожу некоторые, выборочно.
Обратите внимание на "лишние" фонемы в санскрите.
Чем можно объяснить их наличие, если исходить из традиционного взгляда на историю, что культура Древней Индии гораздо старше Русской культуры?

Брат – бхратрь.
Буран – бхурана.
Дочь – духитар 
Дым ‒ дхумена.
Дурной  ‒ дурьяна.
Жизнь – дживатва.
Куда – кутас.
Мга – магна.
Мёд – мадху.
Нить – нитья.
Пал (горение) – палита.
Смерть – мрьтью.
Снег – снехья (скользкий).
Стан – стхана.
Столб – стамбха.
Суть – сатьям.
Сын – суну, сунна.
Шибко – шибхам.
Шурин – швашурья.
Это – этад.

Comment:  Да тем же, чем объясняют изменение "Йоханана" в "Ивана". Упрощение, подгон под своё произношение и, возможно, по ассоциации с чем-то родным.

Comment: Интересно.

А как же Ваше утверждение: Законы" очевидны. "Краткое слово" тут – это корень, а "длинное" – корень, увешанный русскими морфами... ?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы все-таки сказал, что сначала было короткое слово или даже буква, а потом из нее происходили производные и потом упрощались до неузнаваемости. Если коротко, то сначала ситуация, а потом под нее правило.

Приведу пример: Есть русское, а точнее славянское слово "даром" или просто "дар".
Кому-то оно не понравилось и решили сделать производное "без денег", поскольку, помимо денег, существует плата услугами и бартером, то сделали "без оплаты", потом решили еще упростить и начали говорить "безплатно", поскольку подобное выражение трудно в звучании, то правилом заменили "з" на "с" - и получилось слово с совершенно другим звучанием:
http://zdravyi.ru/bes-bez.php

"БЕЗ" – это отсутствие чего-то,
а "БЕС" – это одно из имён... сами знаете кого, поэтому вместо короткого и понятного слова появляется совершенно другое и с другим значением.

В славянской азбуке каждая буква имеет свой образ:
http://www.knlife.ru/slavyanskaya-azbuka.html и http://www.slavianin.ru/nasledie/stati/slavyanskaya-azbuka.-znachenie-bukvits.html

Искажение имен также происходит по принципу эгоизма или гордыни, когда хочется создать то же самое, но свое с другим названием.
Напоминает детей, когда они создают сленг, понятный только им и больше никому!!!

Дейл Карнеги говорил: Вселенная-это большой стол заказов и каждый получает то, что просит с последствиями своих желаний.
Наглядно это продемонстрировано в Ералаше, когда мальчик попросил Джина о трех желаниях:
1) хочу крутую тачку;
2) хочу телок; 
3) хочу много бабок.
Получил:   
1) крутую тачку с ручками, одним колесом, но с магнитолой фарами и аккумулятором, которые сам и таскал за ручки;
2) получил стадо коров (много телок);
3) получил кучу бабушек с носовыми платками (вместо денег).

Нужно уметь правильно и понятно выражать свои мысли, и тогда Вас начнут правильно понимать!!!
С уважением, Алексей!

Comment: Интересно, Алексей!
Правда, несколько отошли от тематики.
Вопрос в том: что могло быть раньше - короткое или длинное слово?

Я привел примеры, где длинные слова из очень древнего языка (санскрита) повторились в русском, как болеее короткие.

Ранее я приводил наоборот - короткий санскрит - в длинные русские слова.

Comment: И таких примеров море. Притом самых различных русско-иностранных парах.

Comment: Думаю, что все-таки короткое, но может не совсем правильно или удобно звучащее и решили переделать с искажениями.
За интерес, Спасибо!
С уважением, Алексей!

Comment: В том-то и дело, Алексей!

Лингвистика упорно стоит на том, что слова исторически менялись по неким законам звукообразования и т.п. Им и в голову не придет, что кроме прочего могли быть просто произвольные акты по переделке слов и выражений. Я наблюдал это явление, в том числе, в Средней Азии как раз в самые яркие 80-90 годы.

Comment: Вот, например, если взять русское выражение "НЕ ОБИТАТЬ" (НЕОБИТАЕМЫЙ), в латинском это INHABITABILIS - НЕОБИТАЕМЫЙ, непригодный. 

Понятно, что такое совпадение не случайно, и кто-то у кого-то здесь непременно заимствовал. Но, если латины действительно очень древние, и русским пришлось у них заимствовать, то как русским пришло в голову из лат IN получить отрицание НЕ? Удивительно!

Кроме того, в английском с этим INHABITABLE вообще оказия.  По-английски INHABITABLE означает нечто противоположное - ПРИГОДНЫЙ ДЛЯ ЖИЛЬЯ, для заселения.

Comment: 
Видите сколько интереснейших проблем!
А лингвистика все еще отнекивается, свалиявая такие примеры на якобы случайное совпадение!

Comment: Я наблюдаю это и сейчас причем повсеместно, когда думают об одном, говорят совершенно другое, а делают третье...
С уважением, Алексей!

Answer (score 0):

Друзья!

Все просто. Современное сравнительное языкознание вооружено собственными законами, долженствующими обосновывать картину, сложившуюся в истории языков. Вероятно, один из законов, который мы здесь услышали, это то, что праязыки по отношению к своим более поздним потомкам могли иметь в своем составе именно более короткие лексемы (слова), т.к. просто еще "не успели" бы обрасти так называемыми флексиями.

Я же показал, что этот процесс имеет вполне реверсный (обратный) характер.
Что может свидетельствовать о том, что идея о ранних (пра)языках, как более укороченных (в отношении своих лексем) - весьма неустойчивая, и не может служить твердый основанием в науке о языке.